# clock works but "python doesn t respond" error after a few seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime

clock = Tk()
clock.title("WhatAClock")
clock.geometry("300x400")

notebook = ttk.Notebook()
tab1_timedate = Frame(notebook)
tab2_alarm = Frame(notebook)
tab3_timer = Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(tab1_timedate, text="Time and Date")
notebook.add(tab2_alarm, text="Alarm")
notebook.add(tab3_timer, text="Timer")
notebook.pack(expand=TRUE, fill="both")

def timedate_realtime():
    time_str = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    l1_timedate.config(text= time_str)
    l1_timedate.after(500, timedate_realtime)
 
def alarm_realtime():
    H_str = strftime("%H")
    M_str = strftime("%M")
    S_str = strftime("%S")
    l1_H.config(text= H_str)
    l2_M.config(text= M_str)
    l3_S.config(text= S_str)
    l1_H.after(500, alarm_realtime)
    l2_M.after(500, alarm_realtime)
    l3_S.after(500, alarm_realtime)
    
l1_timedate = Label(tab1_timedate)
l1_timedate.place(x=100, y=45)
l1_H = Label(tab2_alarm)
l2_M = Label(tab2_alarm)
l3_S = Label(tab2_alarm)
l1_H.grid(column= 1, row= 1)
l2_M.grid(column= 3, row= 1)
l3_S.grid(column= 5, row= 1)

timedate_realtime()
alarm_realtime()                                            
clock.mainloop()
```

Total noob btw. It was doing fine untill i added the time in the second tab, now it works just as well but only for 3 or 4 seconds!
I read it could have to do with a function calling inaccuracy but i still dont t know what to do :(

Comment: BTW, please use the `{}` button (or a line with only three backticks at the start and end of each code section) for code formatting. Adding newlines between every subsequent line of code makes it hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I don t exactly know what you mean

Comment: instead of adding 3 timers, at the exact same time, to call the exact same function, just use one. It's ironic that everything except `clock` is managing the time. `clock.after(500, timedate_realtime)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def alarm_realtime():
    H_str = strftime("%H")
    M_str = strftime("%M")
    S_str = strftime("%S")
    l1_H.config(text= H_str)
    l2_M.config(text= M_str)
    l3_S.config(text= S_str)
    l1_H.after(500, alarm_realtime)
    l2_M.after(500, alarm_realtime)
    l3_S.after(500, alarm_realtime)
```

Every time `alarm_realtime` executes, it asks tkinter to run itself three times in 500 milliseconds. Then when each of those execute, they each ask tkinter for another three executions, for a total of nine. 500 milliseconds later, the 9 instances of the function request 27 executions. After a few seconds, you have millions of instances of the function asking to be called.

Instead of calling `after` three times, call it once.

```
def alarm_realtime():
    H_str = strftime("%H")
    M_str = strftime("%M")
    S_str = strftime("%S")
    l1_H.config(text= H_str)
    l2_M.config(text= M_str)
    l3_S.config(text= S_str)
    l1_H.after(500, alarm_realtime)
```